# Relative complement and subtraction.

Tags: linear-algebra, inner-products

Given two vector subspaces $W_1$ and $W_2$ of an inner product space $V$, 
and $W_2 \subseteq W_1$,
the relative complement of $W_2$ in $W_1$ is defined as $W_1 \cap W_2^\perp$, and some book uses the notation $W_1 - W_2$.

But the notation $W_1-W_2$ is more commonly used to represent $\{w_1 - w_2: \forall w_1 \in W_1, w_2 \in W_2\}$, which is $W_1$ here because $W_2 \subseteq W_1$.

Since I can't figure out, I wonder if there is some connection between the two definitions: relative complement and subtraction between two subspaces? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

In set theory, for two sets $A$ and $B$ we we have $A \cap B^c = A \backslash B = A - B$.

There is no relationship between the relationship you stated.

$\hskip2.5in$ [image]

Comment: Thanks.How similar is orthogonal complement $W_2^\perp$  to the complement $B^c$? Therefore how similar is the relative complement to the set difference?

Comment: @Tim, note that $W_2^\perp \cap W_2 = \{e_v\}$

Comment: What is $e_v$?.

Comment: Identity element of $V$, which is the $0$ vector